# List element access in spring form using index

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Controller Coding

```
 List<Map<String,Object>> rows=globalDao.list("select * from hosp_conf");    
 System.out.println(rows.get(0).get("hosp_id"));
 model.addObject("list",rows);
 return model;
```

View File

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="${rows.get(0).get("hosp_name")}" required>
```

I want to access my list element in spring form using specific index.

Above Sysout stament print excat value in console

How can I access it?

Answer (score 1):

In jsp you can access a list index using the syntax - 
${list[index]}.

In your jsp[, you need to use model attribute name that you have added at your controller.So instead of use rows you need to use list.

I don't know about the object in your list. But you can try like this -

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="${list[0]["hosp_name"]}" required>
```

Comment: Use jstl to iterate a list. For example - <c:forEach items=${list} var='aItem'>(Do whatever you want using aItem)</c:forEach>